# Mirrors in yum cache

Tags: linux

I am trying to find all mirrors inside a yum cache. But I don't understand what kind of files these mirrors actually are.

I resolved my problem in this way:

```
find /var/cache/yum -type f -name "*"
```

But I am not sure about my conclusion about files that I can find using command above.
Can anybody give me the answer what resolutions have mirrors files and how I can find them?

Comment: What is your conclusion? Please try to rewrite your question. Be as specific as possible and ask directed questions. Always include all steps to reproduce, so we can help.

Comment: Jeroen Peeters, I did what you said. I think know everything is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum -v repolist enabled
```

Using this I can list all the enabled repositories on my system with all mirrors(files as `http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release`.  )

Answer (score 0):

Yum cache mirrors are url addresses in *.txt files.
They are located in /var/cache/yum/ directories.

```
find /var/cache/yum/ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep 'http://.*' {} +
```